# Training a decision tree on two different feature sets python scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a decision tree using scikit. One of my feature sets looks something like this:

```
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = ['a','b'] #class labels 
The other feature set looks like this: 
Z = [[1,2,0.5],[2,1,0.5],[0.5,2,2]
Y = ['a','b','a'] #class labels
```

I know that if I have only one feature set, I can do this:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

To consider the Z feature set too, should I do just another:

```
clf = clf.fit(Z, Y)
```

Or will this just overwrite my fit for X?

The number of samples in X and Z are different, which is why I can't just zip them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.fit()` will overwrite any attributes of the object.

One possibility here would be two train two classifiers on independent features and labels, and combine them to "*vote*" on the final output.

For example, initialize two classifiers with similar labels but different feature sets:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y1 = ['a','b']

Z = [[1,2,0.5],[2,1,0.5],[0.5,2,2]]
Y2 = ['a','b','a']

clf1 = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, Y1)
clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(Z, Y2)
```

Now if you have new test examples:

```py
X_new = [[0.5, 0.5], [1, 1]]
Z_new = [[1, 1, 1.8], [2.1, 1.5, 0.8]]

y1_pred = clf1.predict(X_new)
y2_pred = clf2.predict(Z_new)

# y1_pred = ['a' 'b'], y2_pred = ['a' 'b']
```

The easiest way to "*vote*" would be to take the mode of independent decisions:

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

y_pred = np.vstack([y1_pred, y2_pred])

print(stats.mode(y_pred)[0])
# [['a' 'b']]
```

Since the mode is calculated with two objects: tie-breaking may be necessary, but would be domain-specific.

There is a similar problem in semi-supervised machine learning called "[co-training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-training)" that uses independent feature sets. The literature on this problem may yield some insight to this problem.